# R: Error in setwd("C:/Users/diegoesparza/GitHub/covid_equity") : cannot change working directory. Why can't I change my working directory?

Tags: r, working-directory, setwd

I have a folder named GitHub and a folder inside that one named covid_equity. I could only find similar examples where people tried to change their working directories to a file rather than a folder.
When I enter getwd(), I get /Users/diegoesparza.

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/diegoesparza"
```

When I try to read in a .csv from covid_equity, using

```
college_data_tibble <- read_csv("college_data_tibble.csv")
```

I get that the file does not exist in the current directory. But when I try:

```
college_data_tibble <- read_csv("GitHub/covid_equity/college_data_tibble.csv")
```

it works. Then I am not sure why

```
setwd("C:/Users/diegoesparza/GitHub/covid_equity")
```

returns the error "cannot change working directory.
I bought a new computer yesterday and downloaded the .csv files from an email I sent from my old computer, copied them from Downloads and pasted them into the covid_equity folder that is inside the GitHub folder.

Edited:
results from getwd() put into code format

Comment: what does `getwd()` show?

Comment: @Eyayaw, that's in the first paragraph (albeit not `code`-formatted).

Comment: I find only one link when searching [`site:github.com/rstudio/rstudio "cannot change working directory"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%2Frstudio%2Frstudio+"cannot+change+working+directory"), and it links to [rstudio/#4030](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4030). One of the recommendations there was to upgrade to RStudio-1.3 (I'm inferring with little rationale that it's related to projects, perhaps a weak assumption). You might try updating (if < 1.3) and/or restarting R and RStudio.

Comment: `setwd("")` and the pressing tab inside the quotes should take you where you want. Try for example `setwd("~/ and then hit tab")`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I ended up creating a new project in R and locating it inside of covid_equity. There was probably a better way, but this worked well enough for me. @Eyayaw: that feature looks very helpful. I only tried it after creating the new project so I'm not sure if it would have worked.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.